Does strict decrease in magnitude imply quasi-nonexpansivness?
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be monotone, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \langle x-y, F(x) - F(y)\rangle\geq 0,
\end{equation}
and $L$-Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \|F(x) - F(y)\|\leq L \| x-y\|,
\end{equation}
for some $L>0$. Moreover, suppose that $\exists x^{*}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $F(x^{*})=0$.
My question is: Does $\|F(x)\|<\|F(y)\|$ imply that $\|x-x^{*}\|\leq \|y-x^{*}\|$?

Even if $F$ is strongly monotone, this is not true. Consider
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
x &\text{for } x \ge 0,\\
2 x & \text{for } x < 0.\end{cases}
$$
This is strongly monotone with constant $1$ and Lipschitz with constant $2$.
However, $x^* = 0$, $\|F(1)\| = 1$ and $\|F(-2/3)\| = 4/3$.
